# Angular - No pipe found with name

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9, web-frontend, angular-pipe

I've created a pipe using "ng g pipe" command. I'm getting a console error when I'm using it in my code.
The screenshots of the code are attached below.
Error: **error NG8004: No pipe found with name 'filterByPrcName'**.
[filter-by-prc-name.pipe.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENM38.png)[Console Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9A7yF.png)
[product-list.component.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUuyT.png)

Comment: You need to add it to the declarations array of the module.  If you want to expose it to other modules that import the module it's declared in, you'll also need to add it the exports array.

Comment: Thanks @JasonWhite. I missed to export it. It's working fine now.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to open the angular module that declares your component, then add it to the declarations, and add the needed import.

Example:

```
 <td>{{product.productCode | lowercase | convertToSpaces: '-' }}</td>
```

> ERROR in src/app/products/product-list.component.html:48:61 - error
> NG8004: No pipe found with name 'convertToSpaces'.

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProductListComponent } from './products/product-list.component';
import { ConvertToSpacesPipe } from './shared/convert-to-spaces.pipe'; // <-- Add this

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProductListComponent,
    ConvertToSpacesPipe  // <-- Add this
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],

  //exports: [AppComponent],

})
export class AppModule { }
```

convert-to-spaces.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core'

@Pipe({ name: 'convertToSpaces' })

export class ConvertToSpacesPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: string, character: string): string {
        return value.replace(character, ' ');
    }

}
```

Comment: Not working for me implement using with ionic 4

Comment: It's not sufficient to declare it, It needs to be exported, too.

Comment: And if you want to inject the pipe into a constructor, to use it from code, it will have to be included as a provider, too.

Answer (score 96):

Make sure that you put your pipe inside both `providers` and `declarations` of its module, as you will also get this error when your component is not in the declarations array:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
     ...  
  ],
  declarations: [
     MyComponent,
     FilterByPrcNamePipe           // <-- Add pipe here
  ],
  exports: [MyComponent],
  providers: [FilterByPrcNamePipe] // <-- And also here
})
export class MyModule {}
```

Comment: Very underrated answer IMHO. This is usually a very hard to catch.

Comment: This is the truth that everyone needs!!!
Go to your modules and add this particular class in the declarations section

Comment: I occasionally get this error message in VS Code, although my code is correct. I just have to open the `xxx.module.ts` file and the problems go away immediately. Maybe someone else have the same problem...might be a bug which will be fixed in the future.

Comment: Adding to @MikhailRatner - In frustration we often forget to `Ctrl + R` or `F1 -> Reload Window`

Answer (score 13):

I was facing this error when I was using currency pipe in lazy loaded module, for this you have to import **CommonModule** both in current module and in app.module.ts

For modules which are not lazy loaded no need to import **CommonModule**

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answers above, if you have the pipe in a SharedModule, make sure you add the pipe in its exports array also

Answer (score 2):

I spent ages trying to solve this problem when modifying code others had implemented, labouring over what I was missing in app.module.ts of if the latest version of Angular had changed things, when finally I discovered that there was another 'module' in the codebase in addition to app.module.ts.

When I finally figured this out and made the code modifications as per [@live-love](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62683515/1371408)'s answer, including pipe declarations in the other module instead of app.module.ts, it finally worked - phew!

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if you are using the class name of the pipe in the HTML template, instead of using the actual name that was used when the pipe was declared

In my template I was using 'TrustHTMLPipe' instead of 'trustHTML'
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you imported your pipe into a *sharedmodule* 's declarations, at first added this module into your current component's module.

Sample:

```
import { SharedModule } from '@shared/shared.module';

  imports: [
  ...
  SharedModule ,
  ...
]
})
export class SettingsModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have built an Angular library (as a multi-project), be sure to add `my-thing.module.ts` to `public-api.ts`

Snippet of my `public-api.ts`

```js
export * from "./my-thing/my-thing.module";  // Don't forget this line!
export * from "./my-thing/my-thing.service";
export * from "./my-thing/list-my-thing/list-my-thing.resolver.service";
export * from "./my-thing/list-my-thing/list-my-thing.component";
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem and the solution was to add (CommonModule) inside the file (moduleName.module.ts) inside (imports array) and the problem was solved.

I hope I have been helpful to you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaMdH.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).