# Angular datepipe cannot be found

Tags: angular

I want to use the DatePipe in HTML

`{{ timeslot | date }}`

but I get the error

`error NG8004: No pipe found with name 'date'`

My app.module.ts imports the common module

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
     CommonModule,
  ],
  declarations: [],
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular - No pipe found with name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62161219/angular-no-pipe-found-with-name)

Answer (score 8):

Try to put your component in `declarations` like:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
     CommonModule,
  ],
  declarations: [YourComponent],
}
```

Comment: component should always be declared before used

Answer (score 8):

All I want to do is use Angular pipe in HTML.

`{{ timeslot | date }}`

I spent 2 hours on this issue troubleshooting and Google searching the error message,

`error NG8004: No pipe found with name 'date'.`

only to get the same repeated advice for adding CommonModule to imports, or adding to providers then inject into the Component and Service files.

To help those who made the same silly mistake as I did, please check you have **added your component into the app.module.ts declarations** first. You don't even need to do any thing else (import CommonModule whatsoever) to use Angular pipes.

Comment: that's why is better to create components with angular-cli instead of manually ;)

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos I did use the cli, but I inevitable removed the component while editing the app.module.ts file.... sad day for me.

Comment: spent like 2 hrs on this issue with another person and now this saved my day!!

Comment: One note here is for those using standalone components. In this case you will need to import `CommonModule` as each component needs to dictate it's dependencies individually.

Answer (score 1):

For larger, more complex apps, make sure the whole dependency tree is correctly imported.

I suffered this error because a piece was missing in a parent module file. Specifically, the component with the error did not have its declaring module imported into the main app module. Everything else was correct: imported the CommonModule from Angular (for the `date` pipe), declared the erring module in its own module, exported the erring module from its own module.

Comment: This happened to me. I removed a component and the connected module was not compile. All I had to do was remove the reference to the deleted component in the module and everything built