# Unknown Pipe in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

In the `indice` page, I would like to format the number to two decimal  in the `cours` column.

Example: `11345.654589` to `11345.65`.

[image]

I created a `format-num.pipe` folder in `shared/pipes`.

**pipes.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule, DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { FormatNumPipe } from './format-num.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    FormatNumPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],

  providers: [
    DecimalPipe,
  ]

})
export class PipesModule { }
```

**format-num.pipe.ts**

```
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'formatNum'
})
export class FormatNumPipe implements PipeTransform {


  constructor(private decimalPipe: DecimalPipe) {
  }

  transform(input: number | string | null | undefined, digitsInfo?: string): string | null {
    return this.decimalPipe.transform(input, digitsInfo);
  }

}
```

**indice.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { IndiceComponent } from './indice.component';
import { PipesModule } from 'src/app/shared/pipes/pipes.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    IndiceComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    PipesModule,
  ]
})
export class IndiceModule { }
```

**indice.component.html**

```
<td class="text-end"> {{ indiceData.valeur | formatNum:'1.2-2' }} </td>
```

The error message is:

```
src/app/views/dashboard/views/market/views/indice/indice.component.html:18:66 - error NG8004: No pipe found with name 'formatNum'.

18  <td class="text-end"> {{ indiceData.valeur | formatNum:'1.2-2' }} </td>
```

My code is available on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-3ltu6b?file=src/app/views/dashboard/views/market/views/indice/indice.component.html).

On this page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69100715/angular-datepipe-cannot-be-found?noredirect=1&lq=1)... They say that it's a problem with the module declaration? But I made a declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you miss to export your pipe.

In **pipes.module.ts**:

```
exports: [
    FormatNumPipe
  ],
```

NOTE: you have an error (an extra '}') at the final of the *format-num.pipe* file.