# Angular 14, No pipe found with the name 'date'

Tags: angular

I'm using Date pipe in app.module.ts page

component.html:

```
<a>{{req_details.deadLine | date:'mediumDate'}}</a>
```

app.module.ts:-

```
import {DatePipe} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    DatePipe
  ],
```

please help on this where I did mistake.

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)? You need to import `CommonModule`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular datepipe cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69100715/angular-datepipe-cannot-be-found)

Comment: Hello, Did you solve the problem ?I am getting the same error in my angular 14 project.I added CommonModule but it didn't.

Comment: Currently having this error on angular 16.. being stuck on this for almost a day.

Answer (score 2):

Try add Common Module to your imports

```
imports: [
    CommonModule,
]
```