# ngFor not working inside dynamically loaded components

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-dynamic-components

My 16.1.4 angular app is dynamically loading a component.  Inside that component I have an array and am trying to use ngFor. ngFor will not display anything.  If I show the number of entries in the array I'm trying to loop it correctly shows the right number.  It just won't loop through my array.  No errors in console either.

```
START BREADCRUMB: {{components.length}}
   <span *ngFor='let component of components;'>
      {{component.title}}
   </span>
END
```

All that renders in my browser is START BREADCRUMB: 2 END

In other components that are not dynamically loaded, ngFor works as expected.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by dynamically loaded ?

Comment: I am using ComponentFactoryResolver and createComponent to dynamically create my child components and then it's rendered in an ng-template

Comment: You should share more code or even a stackblitz of your issue to investigate what your issue really is !

Comment: I tried.  I can't reproduce in StackBlitz.  I found a basic dynamic load component example, forked it, added an ngFor and of course it worked.  That's why I'm asking on ideas how to troubleshoot an issue like this.  All I can think of is something higher up is breaking it? But no errors are logged in console.

Comment: Without a repro this is hardly actionnable. did you check the dom, are the spans created ?

Comment: No spans, but I do see <!-- container -->

Comment: See what `{{components[0]?.title}}` and `{{components | json}}` yield. Outside the loop obviously

Answer (score 0):

The credit for this answer really should go to @Benny for his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76948520/ngfor-not-working-inside-dynamically-loaded-components?noredirect=1#comment135654062_76948520)

Your tip indirectly helped me find the issue. When I tried the json pipe I got an error that it was not found.  Googling that error led me to [No pipe found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62161219/angular-no-pipe-found-with-name) which led me to realizing my dynamic component was not declared in my parent module. As soon as I declared it, my ngFor's started working.